# Woocomerce Wordpress Conditional Tags

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Is there a possibility to use a kind of conditional tags in WordPress with Woocomerce?

```
<script type="text/template" id="tmpl-variation-template">
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-description">{{{ data.variation.variation_description }}}</div>
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-price">{{{ data.variation.price_html }}}</div>
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-availability">{{{ data.variation.availability_html }}}</div>

  <div class="woocommerce-variation-custom_field" id="preview-spotify">
  <iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/{{{ data.variation.cfwc_spotify_url}}}" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
  </div>

</script>
<script type="text/template" id="tmpl-unavailable-variation-template">
    <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Sorry, this product is unavailable. Please choose a different combination.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
</script>
```

This is my template, and I want to print the woocommerce-variation-custom_field div, only if there is the data.variation.cfwc_spotify_url set.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the evaluate tags `<# #>`

```
<# if ( data.value ) { #>
   your code here {{{ data.value }}}
<# } #>
```